# Adding dummy rows to SELECT statement

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the following select

```
SELECT  f.id, f.name
    FROM  app_fields f, app_forms_tabs t
    WHERE  f.type NOT IN ('fieldtype_action')
      AND  f.id IN (264,271,273,158,160,272,268,263)
      AND  f.entities_id='21'
      AND  f.forms_tabs_id=t.id
    ORDER BY  FIND_IN_SET(f.id, '264,271,273,158,160,272,268,263')
```

which returns

```
id    name
264   L3 PO Grid Assigned
271   Multilevel Dropdown
273   Dropdown Multiselect
158   Name
160   Description
272   Dropdown List
268   L2 PO Grid Assigned
263   Date Assigned to L2 PO Grid
```

What I would like to do is insert some 'dummy' ids in to the f.id IN list which would normally error the query. Something like;

```
264,271,273,st_1,158,160,272,st_2,268,263
```

and then have those 'dummy' rows show in the returned rows so that f.id is the dummy st_ and f.type is empty text so I get the following returned

```
id    name
264   L3 PO Grid Assigned
271   Multilevel Dropdown
273   Dropdown Multiselect
st_1
158   Name
160   Description
272   Dropdown List
st_2
268   L2 PO Grid Assigned
263   Date Assigned to L2 PO Grid
```

Is this possible in the SQL statement?

thanks

Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.4.15-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Is that just in relation to my SELECT statement or how to achieve what I want @GordonLinoff?

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer instead.

Comment: @jarlh so are you saying, no it can't be done easily in SQL so manipulate the data elsewhere?

Comment: Correct. A SQL select returns a fixed number of columns, each with a defined data type.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Remove the reference to `t` it may be causing trouble, or at least sluggishness.